# Send an email with xamarin essential

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I use the following sample to sent a simple email.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?tabs=android

The first time when I run xamarin forms app and call the sent method the popup with apps for selection appeared.

I selected Viber for testing, nothing happened but now i can't undo this selection. Every time when i call the send mail the viber opened.

I tried to clear the app data from the settings and unistall-install the app again but i have the same problem.

How can i fix it ? Can i open a dialog with only email clients ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Settings-> Apps-> Viber-> Under the apps settings section clear the settings and now the send method asked me again. Now i want keep in the dialog only mail clients and remove viber,messenger and similar apps

Answer (score 2):

I replace Xamarin.Essential email implementation

```
var message = new EmailMessage
{
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body,
                To = recipients
};
await Email.ComposeAsync(message);
```

with

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("mailto:test@test.com?subject=test&body=test"));
```

Now the dialog has only the available mail clients.

Comment: OpenUri is obsolete as of v.4.3.0. use await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri(""))